# java server to server communication framework (json)

Tags: java, frameworks

I am building an ESB (enterprise Service Bus). This means i need to 
set up tcp connections and communicate with JSON (well not NEED.. but json is light and easy)
I made a server who is able to set up a TCP socket and receive json. This is all very nice but i need to be able to call methods via a tcp connection.

so for example to call a method:

```
{server:pictures, method:changeImage('name')}
```

This is just an example and could change.

my question is: Is there a framework that is able to:

1. set up tcp server
2. receive json messages and call the appropriate method
3. return an answer (in json).

of course json could also be xml but i would rather use json (much cleaner)

thanxs in advance!

Comment: Why are you writing an ESB instead of using one of the existing ones? Does Mule or ServiceMix not offer you what you need?

Comment: I think the open source ESB's are "to big". The offer a lot of functionality and are to complex. In theory ESB's are very simple. They need to know where all servers are located and when they get a request have to send it to the appropriate server. I am not build a complex system. Just a simple system that is able to serve multiple clients with their content

Comment: Kind of funny, "in theory ESBs are very simple", yet in reality they're not. So, which is right?

Comment: well it is like simple http servers. In theory they are very simple. ask for html - get html.. but look at ruby on rails for example.. there we see 10 different database solutions, deployment servers, testing frameworks, benchmark frameworks, polymorthic relationships, timezone support, templating etc!.. i hope this supports my point ;)

Answer (score 1):

A Web Server serving RESTful web services is exactly what you're asking about..

If I were you, I would look into using SOAP based messaging and the WS-* Standards. Things like WS-Federation and WS-AtomicTransactions will allow you to build a more robust ESB.

Answer (score 1):

Any modern Servlet container, perhaps? Running [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html) or [jabsorb](http://jabsorb.org/)? Have you looked at the modern ESB implementations? Sounds like you have a lot of wheel I've seen before here.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to create your own ESB? As I understand it's a quite complex task. Have you considered using existing [open-source solutions](http://java-source.net/open-source/enterprise-service-bus)?

Comment: Yes I did. But I already build an ESB in ruby (but of course that is very slooooow ;) ) So i am rebuilding the whole thing in java. But al the "features" these open-source solutions provide are just to much for a simple content management system.  In my opinion the only thing an esb should do is 1) know where servers are located 2) transform to the appropriate adapter

Comment: Ohw and I am building this for my final thesis (computer science). I am researching if it is possible to use the ESB architecture for web development. In theory this would make it possible to scale, extend and reuse the system for multiple clients